Gravity forms custom posts add product attributes
I am using gravity forms for users to add products to WooCommerce. I have it pretty much working the way I want. However, I need to add attributes to products. How do I make a field that will add to the attributes portion of the product.
I am using advanced post creation with gravity forms and I can see all my product attributes on that screen but nothing I change will actually update the attribute section in WooCommerce.
